# Retrieving data from a plist

Tags: plist

`Okay so I am trying to pull questions and possible answers from a plist file I have created

```
<key>Question1</key>
<string></string>
<key>Answer1</key>
<array/>
<key>4</key>
<string>A</string>
<key>2</key>
<string>B</string>
<key>3</key>
<string>C</string>
```

So I have tried to do this in code from looking a various tutorials, I am only new to this so I know I have it all wrong

so then I want to place the question in an label created in the storyboard and the same with the possible answers????
`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *listPath = [[self docDir]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"work.plist"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:listPath]) {
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"work" ofType:@"plist"]toPath:listPath error:nil]; 

} 
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:listPath];NSLog(@"count: %i", [array count]);

NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                              propertyListFromData:@"work.plist";
self.firstQuestion = [temp objectForKey:@"Question1"];
self.firstanswer = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"Answer"]];`
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this too.

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistpath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"question.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *savedStock = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
     for (int i=0; i<[savedStock count]; i++)
        {
            [A-array addObject:[[savedStock objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"A"]];
            [B-array addObject:[[savedStock objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"B"]];
        }
```